# How to refer to modules directory in public repos - terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am creating RDS database using the terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws repo.

```
    module "db" {
      source                                = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
      version                               = "~> 5.0"
      identifier                            = "${var.name}-db-instance"
      engine                                = var.db_engine
}
```

I want to reference this module db_instance_automated_backups_replication https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/tree/master/examples/complete-mssql#modules  but I am not sure how to refer to it. I want to use automated backup replication for my RDS instance.

I tried different options in source.but nothing seem to work.

```
module "db_automated_backups_replication" {
  source = "../../modules/db_instance_automated_backups_replication"
  source_db_instance_arn = module.db.db_instance_arn

  providers = {
    aws = aws.replica
  }
}
```

I also tried,
source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/modules/db_instance_automated_backups_replication"

source = "git@github.com:terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds.git/modules/db_instance_automated_backups_replication"

It didnt work..

Any pointers on this please?

Answer (score 1):

That inaccessible nested module is only a single resource as follows:

```
resource "aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication" "this" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  source_db_instance_arn = var.source_db_instance_arn
  kms_key_id             = var.kms_key_arn
  pre_signed_url         = var.pre_signed_url
  retention_period       = var.retention_period
}
```

To duplicate the exact functionality you observe in that example, you would simply need to declare the resource instead of the module as follows:

```
resource "aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication" "this" {
  provider               = aws.region2
  source_db_instance_arn = module.db.db_instance_arn
  retention_period       = 7
}
```

which is considerably simpler than attempting to use the module, or actually using it. For your example above in the question it would be as follows:

```
resource "aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication" "this" {
  provider               = aws.replica
  source_db_instance_arn = module.db.db_instance_arn
  retention_period       = 7
}
```

to achieve the exact same result as the module declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I need to call the module using the submodule path.
source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws//modules/db_instance_automated_backups_replication"

Comment: This solution is an example of [Modules in Package Sub-directories](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#modules-in-package-sub-directories) (in case the documentation is useful to a future reader with a similar problem)